# jQuery ImageViewer initiates with strange zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my website of medieval documents I offer the user a simple interface for viewing a high resolution image of the manuscript page using [ImageViewer](http://ignitersworld.com/lab/imageViewer.html). For example, at http://medieval-inquisition.huma-num.fr/doc/MS609-0002, clicking on the image opens the modal viewer where one always gets (wrongly) the following - a super-zoomed fragment near the top left of the image:

[image: bad initialisation]

But it should initialize like this:

[image: good initialisation]

This happens every time the modal viewer opens on the image the first time.

One then has to click an arrow to force the correct zoom.

Any ideas why this is initializing strangely?

Many thanks in advance.

Adding the script:

```
    $(function() {
    var images = [
    {small : 'http://medieval-inquisition.huma-num.fr/data-images/MS0609_0009_sm.jpeg', 
     big : 'http://medieval-inquisition.huma-num.fr/data-images/MS0609_0009.jpeg', 
     title : 'BM Toulouse MS609, F°. 1r'}
    ];

    var curImageIdx = 1,
    total = images.length,
    wrapper = $('#image-gallery'),
    curSpan = wrapper.find('.current'),
    titleSpan = wrapper.find('.title'), // 
    viewer = ImageViewer(wrapper.find('.image-container'));

    wrapper.find('.total').html(total);

    function showImage() {
    var imgObj = images[curImageIdx - 1];
    viewer.load(imgObj.small, imgObj.big, imgObj.title); // 
    curSpan.html(curImageIdx);
    titleSpan.html(imgObj.title); // 
    }

    wrapper.find('.next').click(function() {
    curImageIdx++;
    if (curImageIdx > total) curImageIdx = 1;
    showImage();
    });

    wrapper.find('.prev').click(function() {
    curImageIdx--;
    if (curImageIdx < 0) curImageIdx = total;
    showImage();
    });

    showImage();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, regarding the [options of ImageViewer](http://ignitersworld.com/lab/imageViewer.html#documentation), I think this is the expected behavior since the initial `zoomValue` is 100%.

I'm unable to access your site at the moment, but you can try initializing `ImageViewer` with a small zoom value (eg. 10%).

Edit: another solution would be force the image be within its container:

```
img.iv-large-image {
  max-width: 100% !important;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I believe (looking at other implementations) that 100% means "fill the image area with full picture", and so the zoom is not absolute but rather relative to display space. Also, it seems the university host had a hiccup when you looked at the site. It's back now. Thanks.

Comment: I've added an alternative but I'm not sure whether it will break the zoom functionality...